# SQL Grouping (multiple)

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, count, aggregate

I have been tasked with creating a SQL query which does a couple of things and, being a relative new user to SQL, was hoping the community here might be able to help- I don't necessarily need direct answers, but rather help with what I should be looking for to get the right answers! I have three main tables:

```
Table 1 = Area
Table 2 = Product_Category
Table 3 = Product_Attributes
```

I'd like to do a count of the number of product_categories, and a sum of the entries in Product_Attributes grouped first by Area, then Product_Category, e.g.

```
Area1, ProductCat1, Product_attribute1
Area1, ProductCat2, Product_attribute1
Area1, ProductCat2, Product_attribute2
Area1, ProductCat2, Product_attribute3
Area2, ProductCat1, Product_attribute1
Area2, ProductCat1, Product_attribute2
Area3, ProductCat1, Product_attribute8
Area3, ProductCat2, Product_attribute7
Area3, ProductCat3, Product_attribute3
```

Should give me something like:

```
Area  | productCat    | NoOfProductCat | NoOfAttribs
Area1 | ProductCat1 | 1 | 1
Area1 | ProductCat2 | 1 | 3
Area2 | ProductCat1 | 1 | 2
Area3 | ProductCat1 | 1 | 1
Area3 | ProductCat2 | 1 | 1
Area3 | ProductCat3 | 1 | 1
```

My second challenge is,

I'd like to show the (decimal) ratio of the noofattribs to noofproductcat fields.

My third, and final, challenge (let me know if I should split this into separate questions) - some of my attribs are ages - and I'd like to filter group them (again) so any which are under 30 days old for example are marked as grouped as this month, and a second grouping based on any which are over 30 days (for ease of reference, I'll use the tables above, and call the dates as being either expdate1 for under 30 days or expdate2 for being over 30 days):

```
Area1, ProductCat1, Product_attribute1, expdate1
Area1, ProductCat2, Product_attribute1, expdate2
Area1, ProductCat2, Product_attribute2, expdate1
Area1, ProductCat2, Product_attribute3, expdate1
Area2, ProductCat1, Product_attribute1, expdate2
Area2, ProductCat1, Product_attribute2, expdate1
Area3, ProductCat1, Product_attribute8, expdate2
Area3, ProductCat2, Product_attribute7, expdate1
Area3, ProductCat3, Product_attribute3, expdate1
```

should give:

```
Area  | productCat    | NoOfProductCat | NoOfAttribs | expdate1 | expdate2
Area1 | ProductCat1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
Area1 | ProductCat2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1
Area2 | ProductCat1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1
Area3 | ProductCat1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1
Area3 | ProductCat2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
Area3 | ProductCat3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0
```

Does that make sense?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look for examples of GROUP BY, you will be grouping by Area, productCat. You might need some sub queries to get some of the counts, then join that to your main query to get your results that you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are going to want to do is group by, aggregates, and aggregates with some case statements. Something like this:

```
SELECT Area,
       ProductCat,
       1 AS NoOfProductCat, --It's always 1. Dont know what you want here...
       COUNT(Product_Attribute) AS NoOfAttribs,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Product_Attribue <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS expdate1, --not really sure what your data looks like here
       SUM(CASE WHEN Product_Attribue >  30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS expdate2
FROM yourTable --your joined table
GROUP BY Area,ProductCat
```

Comment: You left out the ratio part but that's just a simple division anyway if I understand it. (And now that I look at it closer I don't understand the point of dividing by 1 just as you didn't either.)

Comment: Yeah the harder part is getting the values, not performing simple calculations on them. And yes the 1 thing. Don't know what's going on there...